# How to do a loop to check if item exists in firebase?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

The pictures below are my database collection. I have two documents:

- In document "1" I have a collection of 8 items
- In document "1B" ihave a collection of 9 items.

When I am calling it in a Data Table as shown below I'm getting error of ***NoSuchMethodError: The getter 'cells' was called on null. Receiver: null Tried calling: cells** in "1" when clicked whereas the document "2" I am getting all the fields as defined.

How can I remove the error and display the data correctly?

[image: Document 1 with 8 fields of stop]
[image: Document 1B with 9 fields of stop]

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class BusInfo extends StatelessWidget {
  BusInfo({
    @required this.routenum,
    this.stop1,
    this.stop2,
    this.stop3,
    this.stop4,
    this.stop5,
    this.stop6,
    this.stop7,
    this.stop8,
    this.stop9,
  });

  final routenum;
  final stop1;
  final stop2;
  final stop3;
  final stop4;
  final stop5;
  final stop6;
  final stop7;
  final stop8;
  final stop9;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        body: DefaultTabController(
            length: 2,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                title: Text(routenum),
                backgroundColor: Color(0xFFBDBDBD),
                elevation: 3,
                bottom: TabBar(indicatorSize: TabBarIndicatorSize.label, tabs: [
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Route Info"),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Tab(
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      child: Text("Timetable"),
                    ),
                  ),
                ]),
              ),
              body: TabBarView(children: [
                Center(
                  child: Column(
                      children: <Widget>[
                        DataTable(
                          columns: [
                            DataColumn(
                              label: Text('Margeot - Victoria'),
                            ),
                          ],
                          rows: [
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop1)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop2)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop3)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop4)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop5)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop6)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop7)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop8)),
                            ]),
                            // DataRow(cells: [
                            //   DataCell(Text(stop8)),
                            // ]),
                            stop9 != null
                                ? DataRow(cells: [
                                    //this is the code if stop 9 is not equal to null
                                    DataCell(Text(stop9)),
                                  ])
                                : null //this is the code if stop 9 is equal to null
                          ],
                          sortColumnIndex: 0,
                          sortAscending: true,
                        ),
                      ]),
                ),
                Icon(Icons.movie),
              ]),
            )));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will solve your issue with empty data row in it

```
stop9 != null
   ? DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(stop9))])
   : DataRow(cells: [DataCell(SizedBox())])
```

Tip : Instead of having stop1 ... stop8/9 , u can create array of string :).

Comment: How can I do the array of string please show me @CJJ2019 ?

Comment: @CJJ2019 i am getting the lines of the sized box using the code given above how to eliminate this please?

Comment: dont know brother try that firebase array thing that ll resolve all of this shit & make your code cleaner

Comment: I made it an array but still error :( please help me on the array

Comment: use for loop to loop over all existing items for(int i =0; i< stop.length; i ++)  create data row ... i hope this help & plz upvote if soln helps

Comment: In the datarow what should i put please last step

Comment: for(int i =0; i< stop.length; i ++)  DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(stop1)),]), and update sdk constrain in pubspec.yaml file

Comment: it is only pushing the stop1 till it ends :(

Comment: rows: [
                            for(int i =0; i< stop.length; i ++)
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop1)),
                            ]),
                            DataRow(cells: [
                              DataCell(Text(stop2)),
                            ]),

Comment: nope use for(int i =0; i< stop.length; i ++) DataRow(cells: [DataCell(Text(stop[i])),]),

Comment: only this line thats it

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Null Aware expressions](https://medium.com/@thinkdigitalsoftware/null-aware-operators-in-dart-53ffb8ae80bb)

Or as another possibility you can rewrite the last part to use evaluation methods that stop the execution when its not going to be needed after the first part of the execution.

this means change the last part to be something like:

```
stop9 ? DataRow(cells: [
     DataCell(Text(stop9))
     ])
    : DataRow(cells: [
      DataCell(SizedBox())
     ])
```

Comment: Can you please show me because I am getting error only for the null it is searching for the stop 9 in the collection 1